# Docker for Windows not using client certificates

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-for-windows

I'm having issue with connecting to private Docker registry.

Setup:

- *Windows10* (using HyperV)
- *Docker for Windows version*: 18.03.0-ce

Steps I did:

1. Placed client certificates in C:/ProgramData/Docker/certs.d/<private_registry_url>/
2. Placed client certificates in C:/Users//.docker/certs.d/<private_registry_url>/
3. Root certificate imported in Windows "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" (otherwise I'm getting "X509: certificate signed by unknown authority")

Result: Executing `docker login <private_registry_url>` and inserting correct credentials gives me:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://<private_registry_url>/v2/: remote error: tls: bad certificate

which means that Docker is not sending correct client certificates. (When I execute `curl -client <file.cert> -key <file.key> https://<private_registry_url>/v2/` with client certificates I'm able to connect.

When I connect to running HyperV machine there is missing `/etc/docker/certs.d/` folder. If I manually create `/etc/docker/certs.d/<private_registry_url>` and put my client certificates inside, everything starts to work! But after restarting Docker for Windows, folder `certs.d` in HyperV machine is missing and I'm not able to connect to private registry again.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: These is GitHub issue for the same thing. It looks like a bug in Docker for Windows https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2231.